# Page returned by POST handler ignored - get blank response (web.py)

Tags: python, web.py, uwsgi

This is using web.py with uwsgi.

When I return page data from a POST handler, the browser receives a blank page instead. GET handlers are working fine for me. The handler is being called correctly, and redirects (web.seeother) will work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, you need to call `web.input()` otherwise the returned data will be ignore (who knows why? is it a bug?)

Comment: if there are data on a socket, you need to read them, otherwise the socket will be clobbered. You should find an error in your webserver logs about connection reset or something similar. If you do not want to change your code, you can setup uWSGI to read body for you using the --post-buffering option